# Search phrase query like org:"AT and T" with org:"AT & T"

Tags: solr, phrase

How to search phrase query like org:"AT and T" with org:"AT & T".

When I search for org:"AT and T", it doesn't match with org:"AT & T", what is the problem?
Can anyone suggest.

My parsed query is PhraseQuery(org:"at t")

Field Type is

```
<fieldType name="text_filter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `<analyzer type="query">` in place of `<analyzer>` if you've done indexing without setting analyzer